# Create Python object from different .py file

Tags: python

In one file I create a class called Robot, but when I try to create an object of that class in another file it says:'module' object has no attribute 'Robot'

main.py

```
import robot as rob
robot=rob.Robot()
```

robot.py

```
class Robot(object):

    def __init__(self):
    return 0
    def otherFunctions():
    return 0
```

And it says: 'module' object has no attribute 'Robot'. 
Where I am making a mistake?

Comment: You're probably importing a different `robot.py`. Add a print statement to the top of robot.py to make sure it's the right one. Or check `rob.__file__`

Comment: Might also be a circular import problem, if one of the files has an import we're not seeing.

Comment: robot.py has no other imports. and main.py has a lot, I can dd them here

Comment: If you create a directory with just these two files in it (and fix the `IndentationError`s in `robot.py`), `cd` to that directory, and `python main.py`, it works, right? If so, there's something different in your _actual_ code that isn't in your example. And that means nobody can diagnose your actual code short of guessing, or helping you to try to debug it, as mhlester did. This is why good questions should contain an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): an example that's sufficient to demonstrate the actual problem you want solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way your code is written is correct (barring removal you've presumably made for conciseness)

When you `import`, Python checks `sys.path` for importing locations, and imports the *first* `robot` it can find.

A couple ways to solve this:

---

```
import robot
print robot.__file__
```

---

> in robot.py

```
print("hello!")
```

---

```
import sys
sys.path.insert('/path/to/correct/robot/')
import robot
```

Comment: it is strange, because it looks like that it imported right robot.py

Comment: When you add the `print` statement, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the syntax in your robot.py file is not correct.  You can correct the errors in the most direct way by changing your robot.py file to look like this:

```
class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def other_functions(self):
        pass
```

Note that I used snake casing for the `other_functions` function.  Don't use camelCasing in Python.  It's not idiomatic.  Also, I added a `self` argument to `other_functions` so you won't get a `TypeError` if you try to invoke it off of a `Robot` instance.

Also, unless your code is truly as simple as you present it, the error might be coming from a circular import.  Make sure you're not trying to import the two modules from each other before they've had a chance to fully execute.

Comment: That's true of his posted code, but it can't actually be his problem (he'd get an exception while importing, before he could even get to the one he's asking about), so presumably it's not true of his actual code.

Comment: Yes, ideally you would get an unhandled exception like a SyntaxError.  However, I'm not sure if you can rely on this completely.  I've witnessed some cases where what looked like a syntax error (and actually was in the sense of it being a typo by me) was actually parsable and led to an object not being available where I was expecting it.  This isn't super likely, but could still happen.

Comment: Sure, there are cases where things that look like syntax errors are not. But that isn't the case here.