# Creating An Object From a Different File in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I am trying a project which involves multiple files. . This object is a composition of two objects. The files are on Py Charm 2020.3. I have tried adding a **init** as shown in this question ([Create Python object from different .py file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767474/create-python-object-from-different-py-file))  The error message I receive is that there is no module. The whole error message is below.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Aku/ImportExports/Message/TellAndReciveMessage.py", line 2, in 
from Tell import TellMessage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tell'

The Tell Message File:

```
class TellMessage:
    def __init__(self, msg:str) -> None:
        self.msg = msg

    def show(self) -> None:
        print(self.msg)


def main() -> None:
    tell_message = TellMessage("hello world")
    tell_message.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#Tell and Receive Message File 


from Message import TellMessage

class TellAndReciveMessage:
    def __init__(self, tell:TellMessage, recived:str):
        self.tell = tell
        self.recived = ""

    def get_recived(self) -> str:
        return self.recived

    def show(self) -> None:
        self.tell.show()
        self.recived = input(">>")

def main() -> None:
    tell = TellMessage("hello world")
    both = TellAndReciveMessage(tell, "")
    tell.show()
    print(tell.get_recived())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


``
```

Comment: Added __init__.py and it still does not work

Comment: There's some inconsistency here. You say the file is called `TellMessage`, then you try to import from a file called `Message`, but then the error says an import on `Tell` failed. Which of those is the correct thing that you're trying to import, because that error did not come from the file you showed us?

Comment: The folder is called Message. The TellAndRecive file main function has the error.

Comment: Adding a builder method appears to have resolved the problem. How do I close the question?

Comment: If you've solved the problem of your own accord, then post your solution as an answer. Answering your own questions is encouraged here, as it helps future viewers who might have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

''''

""""
Init Module of package
"""

"""
Tell Message File
"""

class TellMessage:
def **init**(self, msg:str) -> None:
self.msg = msg

```
def show(self) -> None:
    """
    Command line output
    """
    print(self.msg)
```

def make(msg:str) -> TellMessage:
"""
:param msg: msg to recive
Output: A new Tell and Reicive Class
Note: This function can be called by the other class
"""
return TellMessage(msg)

def main() -> None:
"""
Input: None
Output: None
Note: Outputs result on command line
"""
tell_message = TellMessage("hello world")
tell_message.show()

if **name** == "**main**":
main()

"""
Tell and Recive Message Module
"""

from Message  import TellMessage

class TellAndReciveMessage:
def **init**(self, tell:TellMessage, recived:str):
self.tell = tell
self.recived = ""

```
def get_recived(self) -> str:
    """
    Output: recived string (idenpotent)
    """
    return self.recived

def show(self) -> None:
    """
    Shows output and gets input
    Output: None
    """
    if not self.tell:
        self.recived = input(">>")
        return
    self.tell.show()
    self.recived = input(">>")
```

def main() -> None:
"""
Input: None
Output: None
Note: Runs code and output on command line

```
"""

#Here is the line that fixes it (can call function)
tell = TellMessage.make("hello world")
both = TellAndReciveMessage(None, "")
both.show()
print(both.get_recived())
```

if **name** == "**main**":
main()

''''